# jQuery popup, change it to load a page in frame or ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

How do I change this one, from showing content from the div, to load a .php file (file.php?id=1) What is the best way to do it, through iframe or ajax?

I want to make multiple pages in the popup window, without loading the entire page every time.

Demo.html

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Reveal Demo</title>

        <!-- Attach our CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="reveal.css">   

        <!-- Attach necessary scripts -->
        <!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script> -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.reveal.js"></script>

        <style type="text/css">
            body { font-family: "HelveticaNeue","Helvetica-Neue", "Helvetica", "Arial", sans-serif; }
            .big-link { display:block; margin-top: 100px; text-align: center; font-size: 70px; color: #06f; }
        </style>

    </head>
    <body>

        <a href="#" class="big-link" data-reveal-id="1">
            Fade and Pop
        </a>    

        <a href="#" class="big-link" data-reveal-id="2" data-animation="fade">
            Fade
        </a>

        <a href="#" class="big-link" data-reveal-id="3" data-animation="none">
            None
        </a>

        <div id="2" class="reveal-modal">
            <h1>2</h1>
            <p>This is a default modal in all its glory, but any of the styles here can easily be changed in the CSS.</p>
            <a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a>
        </div>

            <div id="3" class="reveal-modal">
                <h1>3</h1>
                <p>This is a default modal in all its glory, but any of the styles here can easily be changed in the CSS.</p>
                <a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a>
            </div>
        <div id="1" class="reveal-modal">
            <h1>1</h1>
            <p>This is a default modal in all its glory, but any of the styles here can easily be changed in the CSS.</p>
            <a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

jquery.reveal.js

```
(function($) {

/*---------------------------
 Defaults for Reveal
----------------------------*/

/*---------------------------
 Listener for data-reveal-id attributes
----------------------------*/


    $( document ).on( "click", "a[data-reveal-id]", function(ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
        var modalLocation = $(this).attr('data-reveal-id');
        $('#'+modalLocation).reveal($(this).data());
    });

/*---------------------------
 Extend and Execute
----------------------------*/

    $.fn.reveal = function(options) {


        var defaults = {  
            animation: 'fadeAndPop', //fade, fadeAndPop, none
            animationspeed: 300, //how fast animtions are
            closeonbackgroundclick: true, //if you click background will modal close?
            dismissmodalclass: 'close-reveal-modal' //the class of a button or element that will close an open modal
        }; 

        //Extend dem' options
        var options = $.extend({}, defaults, options); 

        return this.each(function() {

/*---------------------------
 Global Variables
----------------------------*/
            var modal = $(this),
                topMeasure  = parseInt(modal.css('top')),
                topOffset = modal.height() + topMeasure,
                locked = false,
                modalBG = $('.reveal-modal-bg');

/*---------------------------
 Create Modal BG
----------------------------*/
            if(modalBG.length == 0) {
                modalBG = $('<div class="reveal-modal-bg" />').insertAfter(modal);
            }           

/*---------------------------
 Open & Close Animations
----------------------------*/
            //Entrance Animations
            modal.bind('reveal:open', function () {
              modalBG.unbind('click.modalEvent');
                $('.' + options.dismissmodalclass).unbind('click.modalEvent');
                if(!locked) {
                    lockModal();
                    if(options.animation == "fadeAndPop") {
                        modal.css({'top': $(document).scrollTop()-topOffset, 'opacity' : 0, 'visibility' : 'visible'});
                        modalBG.fadeIn(options.animationspeed/2);
                        modal.delay(options.animationspeed/2).animate({
                            "top": $(document).scrollTop()+topMeasure + 'px',
                            "opacity" : 1
                        }, options.animationspeed,unlockModal());                   
                    }
                    if(options.animation == "fade") {
                        modal.css({'opacity' : 0, 'visibility' : 'visible', 'top': $(document).scrollTop()+topMeasure});
                        modalBG.fadeIn(options.animationspeed/2);
                        modal.delay(options.animationspeed/2).animate({
                            "opacity" : 1
                        }, options.animationspeed,unlockModal());                   
                    } 
                    if(options.animation == "none") {
                        modal.css({'visibility' : 'visible', 'top':$(document).scrollTop()+topMeasure});
                        modalBG.css({"display":"block"});   
                        unlockModal()               
                    }
                }
                modal.unbind('reveal:open');
            });     

            //Closing Animation
            modal.bind('reveal:close', function () {
              if(!locked) {
                    lockModal();
                    if(options.animation == "fadeAndPop") {
                        modalBG.delay(options.animationspeed).fadeOut(options.animationspeed);
                        modal.animate({
                            "top":  $(document).scrollTop()-topOffset + 'px',
                            "opacity" : 0
                        }, options.animationspeed/2, function() {
                            modal.css({'top':topMeasure, 'opacity' : 1, 'visibility' : 'hidden'});
                            unlockModal();
                        });                 
                    }   
                    if(options.animation == "fade") {
                        modalBG.delay(options.animationspeed).fadeOut(options.animationspeed);
                        modal.animate({
                            "opacity" : 0
                        }, options.animationspeed, function() {
                            modal.css({'opacity' : 1, 'visibility' : 'hidden', 'top' : topMeasure});
                            unlockModal();
                        });                 
                    }   
                    if(options.animation == "none") {
                        modal.css({'visibility' : 'hidden', 'top' : topMeasure});
                        modalBG.css({'display' : 'none'});  
                    }       
                }
                modal.unbind('reveal:close');
            });     

/*---------------------------
 Open and add Closing Listeners
----------------------------*/
            //Open Modal Immediately
        modal.trigger('reveal:open')

            //Close Modal Listeners
            var closeButton = $('.' + options.dismissmodalclass).bind('click.modalEvent', function () {
              modal.trigger('reveal:close')
            });

            if(options.closeonbackgroundclick) {
                modalBG.css({"cursor":"pointer"})
                modalBG.bind('click.modalEvent', function () {
                  modal.trigger('reveal:close')
                });
            }
            $('body').keyup(function(e) {
                if(e.which===27){ modal.trigger('reveal:close'); } // 27 is the keycode for the Escape key
            });


/*---------------------------
 Animations Locks
----------------------------*/
            function unlockModal() { 
                locked = false;
            }
            function lockModal() {
                locked = true;
            }   

        });//each call
    }//orbit plugin call
})(jQuery);
```

reveal.css

```
/*  --------------------------------------------------
Reveal Modals
-------------------------------------------------- */

.reveal-modal-bg { 
    position: fixed; 
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: #000;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.8);
    z-index: 100;
    display: none;
    top: 0;
    left: 0; 
    }

.reveal-modal {
    visibility: hidden;
    top: 100px; 
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -300px;
    width: 520px;
    background: #eee url(modal-gloss.png) no-repeat -200px -80px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 101;
    padding: 30px 40px 34px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
    -box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
    }

.reveal-modal.small         { width: 200px; margin-left: -140px;}
.reveal-modal.medium        { width: 400px; margin-left: -240px;}
.reveal-modal.large         { width: 600px; margin-left: -340px;}
.reveal-modal.xlarge        { width: 800px; margin-left: -440px;}

.reveal-modal .close-reveal-modal {
    font-size: 22px;
    line-height: .5;
    position: absolute;
    top: 8px;
    right: 11px;
    color: #aaa;
    text-shadow: 0 -1px 1px rbga(0,0,0,.6);
    font-weight: bold;
    cursor: pointer;
    } 
/*

NOTES

Close button entity is &#215;

Example markup

<div id="myModal" class="reveal-modal">
    <h2>Awesome. I have it.</h2>
    <p class="lead">Your couch.  I it's mine.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In ultrices aliquet placerat. Duis pulvinar orci et nisi euismod vitae tempus lorem consectetur. Duis at magna quis turpis mattis venenatis eget id diam. </p>
    <a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a>
</div>

*/
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use JQuery load function to load content to containers. see http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: I already tried, but im not sure how to make the code. Im still new at jQuery.

Comment: jquery load allow you to load content from a web request into a container. for example, you can define a div with id="container" and use jquery load to load data with the following script: $('div#container').load('your data url');.

Comment: Could you make an example?

Answer (score 0):

You can use ajax instead of iframe, for better loading content without refreshing the whole page. Iframe may cause cross-browser scripting and may show loading issue.

Comment: But I cant run some jquery code after I had run the Ajax?

Comment: After running Ajax, in the success response, you can execute any jQuery code. There should not be any problem.